# Execute artisan command on every successful laravel mix build

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

How do you execute an artisan command on every successful laravel mix build?

Answer (score 3):

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
let child_process = require('child_process');

mix.js('Resources/js/core-app.js', 'Assets/js')
     .then(() => {
         child_process.exec('php artisan module:publish', {cwd: '../../'}, function(error, stdout, stderr){
             if (error) throw error;

             console.log(stdout, stderr);
    });
});
```